# Magento 2: 2.3.1 Is there a way to 'compact' or improve the UX of the Magento 2 backend?

Tags: admin, backend, interface

Magento 2: 2.3.1 Is there a way to 'compact' or improve the UX of the Magento 2 backend?

Coming from M1 we love the new Wordpressy kind of look of Magento 2. But ... it does take up a lot of space. And after installation of some modules again all the main menus fill up (are Vendors still allowed to enter items into the top navigation level ???!!), settings menus and list become very wide and fll of the screen. The icons in the left navigation bar go down far and we have to scroll. Also we feel half of the screen is taken up by the header part.

**Question**: is there a compact modus? or other method to make better use of the screen in the Magento 2 backend?

Comment: I also have this question. Magento 2's backend is awful IMO.